# Why is this variable different depending on the function?

Tags: javascript, html

So I am making a slideshow plugin for jquery/javascript, and I am currently trying to create a list of all elements with the class name "slideshow". To do this, I define a global variable at the top of the javascript module that calls a function that (should) return the list of elements with the class name "slideshow". Though, for some reason, it returns an empty array, inside the function and out, even though there is clearly a div with a class name "slideshow", **except** when I print the global variable defined at the top of the module inside a separate function (not the one previously mentioned) it works without a flaw.

Here is the html:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="slideshow.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="slideshow"></div>
</body>
```

Here is the javascript/jquery module "slideshow.js":

```
var slideshows = getSlideshows();

function getSlideshows() {
    var slideshows = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow");
    console.log(slideshows); // prints []
    return slideshows;
}

console.log(slideshows); // prints []

$(function test1() {
    console.log(slideshows); // prints [div.slideshow], which is correct.
});
```

Any idea why it is printing different values?

Thanks!

Comment: They all print `[div.slideshow]`... http://jsfiddle.net/kzf6ybae/

Comment: When is `test1()` being fired? Where is this script being loaded (header/footer)?

Comment: They all fire just fine from this end

Comment: Make sure the DOM is ready before you attempt to access `document`.

Comment: test1() is being fired on document load. It is being loaded in the header of the html. I editted my question to make this clear.

Comment: @Robbie since your script is in the head of your document, it is being fired before `<div class="slideshow"></div>` ever has a chance to exist. Since `test()` is fired on document load, it is waiting for the html to be fully rendered before attempting `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: Oh that makes sense! This works! Can you put it in an answer?

Comment: @Robbie yep, should be there now

Comment: _"I am making a slideshow plugin"_ ... the use of global variables is not conducive to plugins. A plain un-prefixed var name like "slideshows" is fairly likely to collide with another plugin or your users own code.  There are many good tutorials about writing plugins and about creating closures and namespaces so you don't pollute the global namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, either you can put your script in the footer or wrap your script and tell it to fire when the document is ready:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var slideshows = getSlideshows();

    function getSlideshows() {
      var slideshows = document.getElementsByClassName("slideshow");
      console.log(slideshows);
      return slideshows;
    }

    console.log(slideshows);
}
```

Otherwise, your script is firing before the html it's trying to reference exists.

Answer (score 1):

Scripts in the `<head>` section execute before the body of the page is parsed, so the `HTMLCollection` that is returned by `getElementsByClassName` is empty when you display it the first two times.

As soon as the document is fully loaded, `test1` runs and the element shows up. That's because [`HTMLCollection` is live](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) : it is automatically updated as the DOM changes.